# Conversation ui control for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, controls, logging, chat

Is there any control to show messages on iOS, similar to the SMS app and a lot of other apps (Viber, ICQ)? It seems many of them are using the same control for this.

Comment: Are you referring to the locked screen display? See this [screenshot](http://www.macobserver.com/imgs/tmo_articles/20120123_mgga_sms_1.jpg)

Comment: No, I mean control where you see conversation and have an input field at the bottom of screen with send button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand Noah's Answer, there may not be a control like that in the iOS SDK, but there are people on [github](http://www.github.com), [bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.com), and [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) who have rolled their own.  See [here](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ssmessagesviewcontroller) for a pretty accurate clone of the messages.app that comes bundled with the iPhone.

Comment: The author say "Since Apple has made in-app SMS part of UI"... So now is possible to use a chat natively? Anyone Know how?

Answer (score 2):

[Layer](https://layer.com/) is one of the easiest ways to integrate chat and messaging features in your apps. With the recent launch of [Atlas](https://atlas.layer.com/), it is even easier to integrate Layer in your app using its fully featured, high performance, 100% customizable UI kit. The important controllers that you can use to simplify chat UI are:

- [ATLConversationListViewController](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Controllers/ATLConversationListViewController.h): A controller that provides an editable list of all Conversations for the authenticated user.
- [ATLConversationViewController](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Controllers/ATLConversationViewController.h): A controller that a scrollable, auto-paginating view of the Messages in a Conversation.
- [ATLParticipantTableViewController](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Controllers/ATLParticipantTableViewController.h): A controller that provides a sortable, searchable table view for selecting a set of participants to communicate with.

For full implementation details about integrating Atlas and Layer in your app, see [Implementing Chat/Messaging in iOS apps with Layer](http://pulkitgoyal.in/getting-started-with-layer-to-include-chat-in-ios-apps/).

Answer (score 1):

No such control exists in the iOS SDK; the third-party implementations you mention are just mimicking the SMS app’s UI. Most implementations of this are based on a UITableView; you’ll pretty much have to roll your own version of it starting from there.